# (object instanceof C) what is the type of C?

Tags: java

I'm try to do something like this

```
public void method(Object obj, Class objClass) {
    if(obj instanceof objClass) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I want to pass Class object or class name and test if that is and instanceof of that.
This don't work, anyone know how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376988/is-there-any-way-other-than-instanceof-operator-for-object-type-comparison-in-ja

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) method of `Class`.

> Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this Class. **This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language `instanceof` operator**. The method returns true if the specified Object argument is non-null and can be cast to the reference type represented by this Class object without raising a ClassCastException. It returns false otherwise.

So you would write

```
if (objClass.isInstance(obj)) ...
```

If you want to do this generically, you can use `.cast` to convert to the type represented by `objClass`.

```
public <T> void method(Object obj, Class<T> objClass) {
  if(objClass.isInstance(obj)) {
    T t = objClass.cast(obj);
    //do something with t instead of obj
  }
}
```